# Discord.py Detecting a nickname change and then changing it back to the previous nickname

Tags: discord, discord.py

```
async def chnick(ctx, member: discord.Member, nick):
    loop = True
    while loop==True:
      await member.edit(nick=nick)
      time.sleep(5)
```

This is the code i have right now. It just loops the nickname change every 5 seconds which makes the bot run very slow. Is there a way you could make it so that it checks for a change in nickname and if it detects one then it sets it back to the previous one.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `on_member_update(before, after)` event.
[More Information in the Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_member_update)

Comment: This is the proper way to go. Just leaving this comment to emphasize that the members intent has to be turned on for this event to fire